# Subscribe to content type hub immediately

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-collection, team-sites, content-type-hub

On my Sharepoint Online I have some content types in a content type hub.

I create a modern team site (a site collection in fact) and I want those content types from the content type hub to be available for this team site creation right after its creation.

I know there's a timer job that updates the site collections but it's way too slow.

My users want this newly created team site to be operational immediately after it's been created.

So, I see two resolutions for this problem:

1. <s>Run the timer job manually</s> (EDIT: not available in Sharepoint Online)
2. Manually add content types I need by code

Since the first of these solutions is not an option in Sharepoint Online, how can I add the content types I need to the site collection myself?

Comment: In SharePoint Online you can't manually run Timer Jobs, you have to wait it out.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently recommended to use the CT Hub in SPO. This is due to the poor and unpredictable performance of the CT Hub timer jobs.

You cannot manually force the job to run. You're at the mercy of the service. I've seen this job not propagate data for up to 72 hours.

Comment: @TreverSeward appreciate this is an old answer but the new Content Type Gallery appears to use a content type hub to publish content types. Do you think Microsoft have improved the reliability of content type hubs in SPO?

Comment: Yes! This is getting much better over time and the job has been improved since my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TreverSeward, that's great to hear.